# Three-Dimensional Metrics as Deformations of a Constant Curvature Metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 3d, differential-forms, conformal-geometry

I read the following paper [Three-Dimensional Metrics as Deformations
of a Constant Curvature Metric](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0104070.pdf) and discovered the following result:

[image: Three-Dimensional Metrics as Deformations of a Constant Curvature Metric]

I have three questions:

(1) Is $h$ also a conformally flat metric?

(2) Is $\boldsymbol{s}$ strictly the gradient of a scalar function, the curl of another field, or both?

(3) Am I safe to assume that the proof of this theorem is valid? I was unable to find a peer reviewed equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding (1) a three manifold is conformally flat if and only if the Cotton tensor vanishes. The Cotton tensor is defined as a linear combination of covariant derivatives of the curvature tensor, and hence, in particular, always vanishes for constant curvature metrics. So yes, $h$ is by definition conformally flat.

Regarding (2) a quick scan of the paper reveals no statement regarding whether $s$ can be taken to be either exact or co-exact, and I don't see a priori any reason why this should be true. (But I have no time to read the paper in detail.)

Regarding (3), the paper is published in *General relativity and Gravitation*, Volume 34, no. 2, in February 2002. So it certainly is peer-reviewed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was confused on why they multiplied a scalar function to a constant curvature metric and not call it a conformal metric. I was unsure of what a 1-form was in terms of Helmholtz's decomposition.